# Convert a string Date and Time to a DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, c#-4.0, datetime-format

I have to run through thousands of Word document and create XML files out of them.  Everything works fine except the Date fields because I'm working in two languages.

Here are a few examples

- DATE: NOVEMBER 24, 2016          TIME: 15:31
- DATE: 28 NOVEMBRE 2016           HEURE: 10H31

I cleanup up the string a bit using the below but I still get the infamous 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

```
IFormatProvider culture = null;
if (m.rdoEnglish.IsChecked == true)
{
    culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-CA", true);
}
else if (m.rdoFrench.IsChecked == true)
{
    culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-CA", true);
}

string dt = "";
dt = m.txtPublished.Text;

if (dt.IndexOf("HEURE:") != -1)
{
    dt = dt.Replace("HEURE:", "");
}

if (dt.IndexOf("H") != -1)
{
    dt = dt.Replace("H", ":");
}
DateTime dt2;
dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", culture);

//Cleaned string looks like this " 28 NOVEMBRE 2016 10:31  "
return dt2;
```

Comment: The cleaned string looks nothing like the format string you're passing to `ParseExact()`. Try making them match.

Comment: `dt = dt.Replace("H", ":");` will replace every single `"H"` with `":"` which will cause problems with months such as "MARCH".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your format string is incorrect, in light of the two examples you gave.
It should be something like "MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm"
Read more about it at: 
[DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The ParseExact, as well TryParseExact, has an overload that accepts an array of formats to use in parsing the string. This will allow you to use something like this

```
string test = dt.Replace("DATE: ", "")
                .Replace("TIME: ", "")
                .Replace("HEURE: ", "");

string[] formats = new string[]
{
    "MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm", "dd MMMM yyyy HH\'H\'mm"
};
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(test, formats, culture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Notice that I don't try to replace the single char H inside the french version of your string because I don't know if the same char appears somewhere in your months.